# htaccess URL redirect based on page title

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I would like to add a line to my htaccess to change this url:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

do this is the url

```
http://site/Calendar/viewevent?eventid=9223
```

into something like this :

```
http://site/Calendar/viewevent/Title-of-event
```

its php and joomla and I am a php developer, please dont advise me to use a component or module to handle redirects, I am trying to achieve this using .htaccess ONLY :) thank you in advance!!

Comment: Try this: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: it doesn't solve the issue but this is awesome thanks Mark!!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it doesnt help the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'pretty' url contains information that is not in the 'working' url. Besides that, the 'working' url also contains information that is not in the pretty url. You need database access to translate the event id to a seo-title, and the seo-title back to an event id. In other words: It is impossible to do this with .htaccess only, unless you change 'viewevent' to accept an event by seo-title, instead of eventid.

Mod_dbd can possible be used, but only in the server config file, not .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

As Sumurai8 says htaccess cant transform url like you want automatically.
But you can use Redirect 301 (or its variation) for one url to another.

for your example:

```
Redirect 301 /Calendar/viewevent?eventid=9223 /Calendar/viewevent/Title-of-event
```

more information [here](http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/301-redirects/)